# The refreshControl not triggered until pull down the list view a long distance

Tags: react-native

When you slightly pull down the listview you'll see the indicator.
However, it doesn't really trigger the onRefresh callback.
How could I really trigger the onRefresh callback when a user pulls down the list view as the indicator shows?

```
    _onRefresh() {
        this.setState({isRefreshing: true}, this.props.refreshWords())
    }


            refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                    refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
                    onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                    title="Refreshing words"/>
            }
```

Comment: Can we see your `onRefresh` method?

Comment: @Li357 pls see my update. the onRefresh method is working fine. But my expectation is to trigger it as we see the indicator no need to pull a long distance

Comment: Unless `refreshWords` returns a function, it should be `this.setState(…, this.props.refreshWords)`

Comment: it's a dispatch method. it's working fine.

Comment: The point is to trigger onRefresh event. it needs a long distance and pull down for 1~2 seconds for triggering it. thanks~